# Take last n columns with value

Tags: r

i have a basic R question: imagine the following code:

```
a <- c("A","B","C")
b <- c("A","B","C")
c <- c("A","X","C")
x <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c("","B","C")
z <- c("","","C")
frame <- data.frame(a,b,c,x,y,z)
```

now i want to get the content of the last 3 columns but only if they contain value. So the Output should look like this

```
new1 <- c("A","X","C")
new2 <- c("A","B","C")
new3 <- c("A","B","C")
frame2 <- data.frame(new1,new2,new3)
```

I am thankful for every help.

Comment: What does "contain value" mean? No NA? Empty "" string? I guess your final frame has more than 3 columns?

Comment: With contains value i mean no empty strings. Sorry and yes my final frame has more than 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` from `base R`

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(frame, 1, FUN = function(x) tail(x[nzchar(x)], 3))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
new_frame <- frame[colSums(frame == '') == 0]
new_frame[tail(seq_along(new_frame), 3)]
  b c x
1 A A A
2 B X B
3 C C C
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I made a mistake how the output should look like. I changed my code above. I want the last 3 columns for each row that is not empty (""). Your answer unfortunately does not give me the wished result.